# Getting error "INTERNAL" when training a model with AutoML

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automl, google-cloud-automl, google-natural-language

I'm training a small model with AutoML entity extraction, but the training keeps failing with the error message "INTERNAL" and no other details.

I'm doing this from the Google Cloud console, and I've followed the same steps I've used successfully to train other models.

The dataset has two labels with a few hundred text items each, so I doubt it's a timeout or anything like that.

What might be causing this and is there a way to debug/get more visibility?

Comment: have u reported to google using the help / screenshot button ?

Answer (score 0):

Could be that dataset contains duplicate columns which is not currently supported. If this is not your case, I'd suggest to reach with [GCP Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) to check it internally.